# Can a v-on directive directly modify a data() property of the parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, eventemitter

I have an application which has Vue components as children.

The components pass back data to the parent via a `this.$emit` (`numberchnaged` below), which is caught at the parent level by a `v-on` (or `@`) directive, which in turns triggers a method.

This method then updates a `data()` property of the parent:

```
<template>
      (...)
      <Users @numberchanged="doNumCh"></Users>
      (...)
</template>

<script>
(...)
export default {
  components: {
          Users
  },
    data() {
      return {
          u: "hello"
      }
    },
    methods: {
      doNumCh(value) {
          this.u = value
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

This solution works but is quite verbose for just updating `this.u` with what `<Users>` sent back.

**Is there a way to make the update right in the `<Users>` tag**, something like

```
<Users @numberchanged="u=theValueReturedByUsers"></Users>
```

**My problem is that I do not know how to extract `theValueReturedByUsers`**, I only get hold of it in the method as `value` (in my example above).

Comment: As far as i know. you are doing it correct. i don't have an idea about your implementation

Comment: It could make things less verbose if you used [v-model for components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Comment: @RoyJ: this is indirectly what I just found (ans posted as an answer), namely `$event` holding the payload. Your comment points to a better solution, though - if you do not mind to turn it into an answer I would gladly accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, you're looking to have `v-model` behavior on your component. Vue [provides for that](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components). So you can say

```
<template>
      (...)
      <Users v-model="u"></Users>
      (...)
</template>
```

which is a tidy view, as long as your `Users` component (side note: you should always [have a hyphen in custom component names](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name)) takes the `value` parameter and `$emit`s the input event.

See also [v-bind.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) to work with props other than `value`.

Comment: Thanks for the `v-model` info. I followed the Vue examples regarding the case (they use e.g. `<HelloWorld>`) but I see with your pointer to the standards that they are wrong (I just read the case does not matter somewhere else in the standard and stopped there). Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The payload is reachable via `$event`.

For the code above, the solution would therefore be

```
<Users @numberchanged="u=$event"></Users>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (without write a method in parent) with using the variable `$event` which contains the value returned  (Object or literal variable) from child component:

```
 <users @numberchanged="{u=$event}"></users>
```